# WinAPI: draw RGBA image

Tags: winapi, gdi, user32, layered-windows

I know there are a lot of answers related with this question, but I read them all and still don't understand.

My target is to draw RGBA image on the top of all windows using WinAPI.

For this I make TOPMOST LAYERED TRANSPARENT window:

```
    hWin = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
                          "WindowClass1",
                          "Title",
                          WS_POPUP,
                          posX,
                          posY,
                          width,
                          height,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);
```

To load image from file I use **stb_image.h.**

And to draw the image I tried different functions, right now it is:

```
    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc,
                      0,
                      0,
                      width,
                      height,
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      height,
                      pixels.data(),
                      &bmi,
                      DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Everything is draws, but without the alpha channel, I can only set the alpha for the whole window using:

```
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWin, RGB(200, 200, 200), /*alpha=*/255, LWA_ALPHA);
```

And also I tried: UpdateLayeredWindow()

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++? Isn't the Windows API in C, and cannot everything relevant be done in C?

Comment: `SetDIBitsToDevice` does not support alpha channels, use the [AlphaBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) function instead.

Comment: @pts - winapi itself is C, but if the person asking is using C++ that affects what they're looking for in example code and help.   Same as if they were using python or C# to call winapi

Comment: Also see the [Alpha Blending a Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/alpha-blending-a-bitmap) example.

Comment: I tried this function, but it seems like it blend bitmap with window background. And I want to blend it with other windows (for example with desktop or browser)

Comment: And also as I understand now I can't draw just one time? Now I should redraw in cycle to blend with changing background?

Comment: For per pixel alpha blending, you should use `UpdateLayeredWindow` but you've not showed how you're using it. How did you try `UpdateLayeredWindow`?

Comment: @jtxkopt, UpdateLayeredWindow() will work the same as AlphaBlend()? I mean blend bitmap with background of window. I need to blend bitmap with another windows (like window with transparent in some places background)

Comment: nvm, UpdateLayeredWindow() works fine. I'm just stupid. ty all

Comment: Would taking a screnshot, drawing the image "into" the screenshot and displaying the result "full-screen" as (non-transparent) image an option?

Comment: @Martin Rosenau, as for me it's bad idea in my case, because I want to interact with other windows (to be more precise: I make sight for any game)